# Check Row when changing pages in GridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

When clicking the pager in a GridView, I want to highlight each row if the amount equals a  certain amount. I have this working when the GridView is first populated, but each time I click the pager button to move to the next page with a valid amount, it will not highlight. Any suggestions?

**GridView**

```
    <asp:GridView ID="ERNDataGrid" runat="server" CssClass="clsGridView" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="15"
        OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" Width="99%">
        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#464646" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>
        <PagerSettings Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" />
        <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" ForeColor="White" BackColor="#464646" Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False"></PagerStyle>
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DDDDDD"></AlternatingRowStyle>
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CUID" HeaderText="Routing Number" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Account" HeaderText="Account" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Amount" DataFormatString="{0:C}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Serial" HeaderText="Check Number" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

**VB.net Codebehind**

```
Protected Sub ResearchGridView_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ResearchGridView.Click
    strResearchAmount = txtERNResearchAmount.Value
    BindData()
End Sub

Private Sub ERNResearch_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        ERNDataGrid.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub BindData()
    'Create a connection
    Dim myConnection As New SqlConnection("This works")
    'Create the command object, passing in the SQL string
    Const strSQL As String = "SELECT CUID, Account, Amount / 100 as Amount, Serial FROM [ACCU].[dbo].[ERN_ITEM_VIEW] Where Date = '04/13/2017' And CUID <> '0'"
    Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(strSQL, myConnection)
    'Create the DataAdapter
    Dim myDA As New SqlDataAdapter()
    myDA.SelectCommand = myCommand
    'Populate the DataSet
    Dim myDS As New DataSet()
    myDA.Fill(myDS)
    'Set the datagrid's datasource to the dataset and databind
    ERNDataGrid.DataSource = myDS
    ERNDataGrid.DataBind()
    'Display Information on what page we are currently viewing
    'lblMessage.Text = "Viewing Page " & ERNDataGrid.PageIndex + 1 & " of " & ERNDataGrid.PageCount
End Sub

Protected Sub OnPageIndexChanging(sender As Object, e As GridViewPageEventArgs)
    ERNDataGrid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    Me.BindData()
End Sub

Protected Sub OnRowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowIndex > -1 Then
        If e.Row.Cells(2).Text = "$" & strResearchAmount Then
            e.Row.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I believe the RowDataBound event is being fired. Can you check if it is and if so what the value is of `strResearchAmount`, since a page change is a postback it it likely that the variable is empty.

Comment: You, sir (@VDWWD), are brilliant! I added `strResearchAmount = txtERNResearchAmount.Value` just inside the OnRowDataBound sub just inside the RowIndex check.

Comment: How do I give credit to a comment? Sorry, still new, but I want to do it right.

Comment: If you hover to the left of a comment, you'll see a little flag with an arrow above it. Click that.

Comment: I do not see the flag (even tried a different browser). From what I am reading, do you mind posting your comment as an answer? I can click the checkbox from there.

Comment: I've added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks correct. The `OnRowDataBound` event is triggered every time `DataBind()` is called. And since that is the case in your `OnPageIndexChanging` the RowDataBound should fire.

However the `strResearchAmount` could be empty since it is filled only after a button click. Since a page index change also triggers a PostBack, it is likely that `strResearchAmount` is empty when OnRowDataBound is called for the second time.

Check the value of `strResearchAmount` and make sure it persists across PostBack.